# Android IME: how to show a pop-up dialog?

Tags: android, keyboard, ime

I'm playing around with some keyboard development and try to show a pop-up dialog when a certain key is pressed

```
if (primaryCode == -301) {
            AlertDialog mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(CONTEXT)
            .setTitle("My dialog")
            .setMessage("Lets do it.")
            .setPositiveButton("ok", null).create();
             mDialog.show();
}
```

However, the problem is the `CONTEXT` part. In a normal application it would just be `this`. I also tried `getApplicationContext()` and `getBaseContext()`, but neither of those works -> keyboard crashes.

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException:
>   Unable to add window -- token null is
>   not for an application

So I'm wondering if I have to do something with [InputConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html):

> The InputConnection interface is the
>   communication channel from an
>   InputMethod back to the application
>   that is receiving its input. It is
>   used to perform such things as reading
>   text around the cursor, committing
>   text to the text box, and sending raw
>   key events to the application.

So far I wasn't able to figure out how. I definitely know it's possible, since I have seen it before. I someone could point me in the right direction that would definitely be appreciated.

---

**Update:**

To provide a better picture of what I try to achieve I uploaded a screenshot of the Swype keyboard, which does exactly that: showing a pop-up dialog when a special key gets pressed on the keyboard.

[image: Swype pop-up dialog]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peace be upon those who follow the guidance,

solution :

```
AlertDialog dialog;
//add this to your code
       dialog = builder.create();
        Window window = dialog.getWindow(); 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
            lp.token = mInputView.getWindowToken();
            lp.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG;
            window.setAttributes(lp);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
//end addons
alert.show();
```

good luck.

Comment: if soft keyboard is open and try to open alert dialog box, Softkeyboard display under the alertdialog box not allow to add text inside the edittext of the alertdialog box

Comment: First of all thank you! For some reason sometimes after I press the positive button, onFinishInputView is being called. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: It is not working for me anymore. Can anyone please help me to open dialog from an ime service? @AmitKlein

Answer (score 4):

An IME does not run in an application context, so you can not use normal application windows.  You can use a Dialog, but you will need to modify its window so that the window type is this type:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL

And set WindowManager.LayoutParams.token to be the token of the IME window (via View.getWindowToken()).

Note that the dialog will not be able to display pop-up windows, because in this case it is itself effectively a pop-up window.  Also the coordinate space will be relative to your IME unless you use the window flags to change it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Additionally looking at the Android's default keyboard source code answered all my questions.

Comment: @hackbod I have tried your suggestion, but it's not working on Android 9. Can you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51906586/display-dialog-from-input-method-service-in-android-9-android-pie?

Answer (score 2):

Make an activity and in the manifest file give that activity the attribute

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get a reference to your activity context.
Anyway, you should use the showDialog method of the Activity.

Comment: Two problems: 1) I'm developing a IME (keyboard), thus it's not my activity 2) How do I get the reference to the current activity? (That's actually my question above)

Comment: One thing is sure, you cannot display any Dialog from the ApplicationContext. Why don't you take a context reference in your constructor of the view ?

Comment: Because it's keyboard service which talks to any text input field of other (not my) applications: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html

Comment: @znq Can you please help me to open dialog from an ime service?

Answer (score 0):

its very simple, just create activity like here (with out any view), write code of dialog in it

```
public class dialog extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Delete All Contacts?");
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //deleteAllContacts();
                        }//
                    });

            builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
}
```

now go to Android manifest file and add activity like,

```
<activity android:name=".dialog" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">        </activity>
```

its all, enjoy

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1. CREATE THE DIALOG
val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light)
builder.setTitle("Title").setMessage("This is the message for the user. ")
val mDialog = builder.create()

// 2. SET THE IME WINDOW TOKEN ATTRIBUTE WITH THE TOKEN OF THE KEYBOARD VIEW 
mDialog.window?.attributes?.token = this.mTblView.windowToken

// 3. SET THE TYPE OF THE DIALOG TO TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG
mDialog.window?.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG)

// 4. SHOW THE DIALOG 
mDialog.show()
```