# Display dialog from Input Method Service in Android 9 (Android Pie)

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

My app includes an Input Method Service with a special button that brings up a dialog. For users with Android 9, this dialog is not displayed correctly, only the part above the IME is visible:

[image]

The code to create the dialog is

```
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
    LatinKeyboardView inputView = mKeyboardSwitcher.getInputView();
    lp.token = inputView.getWindowToken();
    lp.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG;
    window.setAttributes(lp);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);

    dialog.show();
```

which is the same as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13962770/292233

I also tried `TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL` as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3508462/292233 but this doesn't help either.

Is there any easy fix to this?

Comment: Start a dialog-themed activity.

Comment: @commonsware I am considering this, but how would you return data to the IME service? I can't use startActivityForResult from my service.

Comment: If the activity and the service are in the same process, you would use whatever you want. That could be an event bus (e.g., `LocalBroadcastManager`). That could be by both interacting with a singleton repository. And so on. If the activity and service are in different processes, use a `PendingIntent`, or a `Messenger`, or a `ResultReceiver`, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have implemented the activity as a dialog (with theme=) and this works in most cases, but users have pointed out that on Chrome the IME is closed when the dialog pops up and it seems like I cannot input the text to the input field after that anymore. I am using getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM); in the activity's onCreate. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: "users have pointed out that on Chrome the IME is closed when the dialog pops up" -- you don't have control over that. Whether the IME is showing is up to the app that has the `EditText` (or whatever) that triggers the IME. In this case, Chrome may be using `InputMethodManager` to hide the IME when Chrome no longer has the input focus.

Comment: But it doesn't do this with an AlertDialog.  It's a shame that the previous way does no longer work.

Comment: @CommonsWare slightly related, but do you know if it is possible to start a dialog-themed activity from the IME without causing the IME close? The best I've managed is for it to be closed/opened again with "android:windowSoftInputMode".

Comment: @user2891659: No clue, sorry!

Comment: I found that both PopupWindow and Alertdialog show only inside the candidateview and keyboardview.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be fixed by using WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG instead of TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG and requesting android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW.

Detailed change is here:
https://github.com/osfans/trime/commit/d8e9da2dfe2653c94cd4aecba00728b7a910cbb8

Comment: Looking into the detailed changes here and making the change from LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG to instead use LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY worked for me. But you do have to add Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW to your manifest (and the permission granted) per the documentation.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[BTDeviceMaintainerService]
    Process: com.unionpay.smartpos.service, PID: 3926
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Answer (score 0):

If both PopupWindow & AlertDialog do not work, I think we can use floating view, like this:

1. Custom a view, make it look like a dialog.
2. Use WindowManager to add the view, the view will be shown on top of any android application. I have learnt it from [FlowtingExample](https://github.com/koduribalaji/FloatingExample)

I tried using it. It works on Android P. However, this method get serious problem with global keys:

When "the dialog" is showing from keyboard, user press global key like Home key.

=> Home screen is shown. But, "the dialog" & keyboard is still showing.

(Is there anyway to fix this limitation?).

(I heard language selection dialog from Google keyboard (Gboard) works perfectly on Android P. But I cant find source code of Gboard. Is there anyway to get it?)

Sorry I am totally new with stackoverflow, I think I should post this into comment section but I cant do that because I do not have enough 50 reputations.

Comment: Here's an IME: https://github.com/BrainBear/LatinIME. It is ported from AOSP LatinIME. AlertDialog works well when long click comma.